# c# firestore - Additional information: Path cannot contain empty elements

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check if a document exists from my firestore DB but am getting an error before it checks if it exists so I'm a bit confused. I would think my documentsnapshot would return null after the `.GetSnapshotAsync()` call first however it is just tripping an error and not able to get to the `if (docSnapshot.Exists)` line.

Context: I am switching over from realtime database to Firestore so the paths are not the same. In this case, `lastPath` is not empty but it is a realtime database path. Therefore, the line is checking for a realtime database path and is expected to return false.

`lastPath` = MyCollection/Projects/6f8ebcf7-231f-47e5-ac72-2707cd38ae8f/

The error that occurs: `Additional information: Path cannot contain empty elements`

So far, I've tried:

The following code is:

`DocumentReference documentReference = firestoredb.Document(lastPath);` // <<-- throws error not able to continue

and

`DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await firestoredb.Document(lastPath).GetSnapshotAsync();` // <<-- Also throws error.

Here is the code that follows:

```
if (docSnapshot.Exists)
    {
        // do this
    }
    else if (!docSnapshot.Exists)
    {
        // do this instead.
    }
```

I can only think of doing a try-catch but I am hoping there is a better way to check if the document exists.

I checked the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) but I keep getting the error and the other posts I've found on SO show mostly for android.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like `lastPath` is empty. Please edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I have updated the post to show what the `lastPath` variable is equal to. I am trying to move from realtime database to firestore so that may be part of it.

Comment: Your `lastPath` variable ends with a `/`, which means there's effectively an empty path element at the end, which is invalid. Just remove the slash. Although that would then be a collection, not a document (assuming `MyCollection` is a collection).